# Setting schematics variable in angular 6 project

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to add ngrx schematics to angular 6 (version rc5) project.

```
ng set defaults.schematics.collection=@ngrx/schematics
```

but it spits out error:

```
The specified command ("set") is invalid. For a list of available options,
run "ng help".

Did you mean "t"?
```

Question is: how do you set variables in Angular 6 since there is no "ng set" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on `rc.6`. You use `ng config`. You can try it like this:

`ng config <setting> <value>`

This will update the `angular.json` file.

If you look into the `node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json` you will find the schema you are looking for. VS Code even helps with auto completion.

Comment: I am getting this error `Invalid JSON character: "@" at 0:0.` when trying to run the command to set up the ngrx schematics as the default, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@Giovanni Bassi, please can you explain in detail, I am not understating, I have migrated to angular 6,  and my package.json having some custom scripts, like, build-prod-ngsw and ngsw-copy , but when i am running ng build-prod-ngsw it showing below error  .....

```
The specified command ("build-prod-ngsw") is invalid. For a list of available options,
```

run "ng help".
Did you mean "help"?

Below is my package.json file

```
 "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"ngsw-config": "node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config dist src/ngsw-config.json",
"ngsw-copy": "cp node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js dist/",
"build-prod-ngsw": "ng build --prod && npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy"
```

},

Comment: I think you should run those scripts with "npm run build-prod-ngsw". "ng-xx" is only for angular specific commands.